# Combine 2 panda dataframes where indexes are strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

Here are 2 panda dataframes, where the indexes are strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
df.index = ['Tax1','Tax2','Tax1','Tax2']

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0], [1, 1]], columns=list('AB'))
df2.index = ['Tax3','Tax3']
```

which gives for df:

[image]

and for df2:

[image]

Is there a simple way to insert the rows of df2 in df as such:

[image]

without having to remove the indexes strings back to numbers and use df.loc['k']? 
The closest I've been is with append, which puts the 2 rows of df2 at the end of df rather than what I'm looking for...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your sample data in the text of the question ,not as pictures, to make a [mcve]

Comment: if the sample is the same as your df then just concat the dataframes `pd.concat([df,df2])`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. 
G. Anderson, a closer look at my question will show you that df and df2 are included in the text of the question. Pictures are only here for illustration ([1], [2] of what df and df2 look like, and [3] of what I'm trying to get but couldn't).
Datanovice, "pd.concat" doesn't give [3]; instead it adds df2's rows at the end of df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- Add a top level index to *df* (*1* for first 2 rows, and
  *2* for last 2 rows) and save the result in e.g. *wrk1*.
- Add a top level index to *df2* (*1* for first row, and
  *2* for second row) and save the result in e.g. *wrk2*.
- Concatenate both above DataFrames.
- Sort by the MultiIndex and drop its top level.

The code to do it is:

```
wrk1 = pd.concat([df.iloc[0:2], df.iloc[2:4]], keys=(1, 2))
wrk2 = pd.concat([df2[0:1], df2[1:2]], keys=(1,2))
result = pd.concat([wrk1, wrk2]).sort_index().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

**A detail to consider:** The resulting DataFrame contains non-unique
entries in the index, so maybe you should leave the top level of the index
(your choice).

## Edit following your question

Let's look at the intermediate results:

1. *wrk1* - first 2 rows from *df* with index == *1* and second 2 rows
   with index == *2*:

   ```
           A  B
   1 Tax1  1  2
     Tax2  3  4
   2 Tax1  5  6
     Tax2  7  8
   ```
2. *wrk2* - first rows from *df2* with index == *1* and second row
   with index == *2*:

   ```
           A  B
   1 Tax3  0  0
   2 Tax3  1  1
   ```

One option to generate the result is its "incomplete" version (without
*reset_index*):

```
pd.concat([wrk1, wrk2]).sort_index()
```

It gives the following result:

```
        A  B
1 Tax1  1  2
  Tax2  3  4
  Tax3  0  0
2 Tax1  5  6
  Tax2  7  8
  Tax3  1  1
```

Here you have **2 levels** of the index:

- top level - either *1* or *2*,
- second level - copied from your source DataFrames,

so from the top level you see the "source" of particular rows
(either 1st or the 2nd subset) and each row has **unique** index.

The second (full) option is:

```
pd.concat([wrk1, wrk2]).sort_index().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

which gives just what you wanted:

```
      A  B
Tax1  1  2
Tax2  3  4
Tax3  0  0
Tax1  5  6
Tax2  7  8
Tax3  1  1
```

(without the top multiindex level).

Comment: If ever you have a minute: I would love to get what you mean in the detail to consider. Which index entries do you refer to? What is the top level of the index? And how to leave it?
I tried "level=1": it keeps the keys. I tried also "drop=False": it keeps both the "Tax" index and the keys index.

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it! (you're amazing at explaining btw :)).